# Python Created Object Attribute

Tags: python, class, object, attributes, set

I would like to create attributes of an object based on a dictionary passed in as an argument. Here is the code. But it does not work as

```
class Obj(object):
    def __init__(self, di):
        self.a = 0
        self.b = 1
        for k in di.keys():
            name = 'k' + '_' + 'series'
            self.name = None

di = {'c':0,'d':1}
Obj_instance = Obj(di)
print Obj_instance.c_series
```

I get the following error: 'Obj' object has no attribute 'c'

The code read "name" as a literal, and not as the variable defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what will work :

```
class Obj(object):
    def __init__(self, di):
        self.a = 0
        self.b = 1
        for key, value in di.items():
            key += '_series'
            setattr(self, key, value)

di = {'c':0,'d':1}
Obj_instance = Obj(di)
print Obj_instance.c_series
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr)

```
class Obj(object):
    def __init__(self, di):
        for key, value in di.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)
```

Some additional advice:

Your code is very strange. I'm not sure why you expect `self.name` to evaluate as `self.(eval('name'))` when that clearly doens't happen elsewhere in python

```
 lower = str.upper
 str.lower('Hello')  # -> still returns 'hello'
```

There is no need to iterate over `dictionary.keys()`, especially in python 2. `for k in dictionary:` works just fine. If you want both keys and values use `dictionary.items()` (or `dictionary.iteritems()` in python 2).

`name = 'k' + '_' + 'series'` just makes the string `'k_series'`. You need to be able to tell the difference between a string and a variable name. I think you mean `k + '_' + series` but `series` is never defined. Don't use `+` to concatenate strings like that anyway, use [`.format`](https://pyformat.info/).

Comment: This will not add attributes c_series and d_series to  the object

Comment: No but I think the person asking the question *should* be able to figure that out. Just giving them the answer without explaining why does not help them!